# Error in batchGetItem API in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The entity i am querying has a `HashKey` & a `RangeKey` (Number). When i use `batchGetItem` on it, i get the following error:

> AWS Error Code: ValidationException, AWS Error Message: One or more parameter values were invalid: Mismatching attribute types between location and schema

Schema:

> Table: Daily
>
> Hash Key: CustId (String)
>
> Range Key: Dated (Number)

Data:

> CustId : VisioNerdy
>
> Dated : 1329071400000

Code:

> ```
>   List<Key> fkeys = new ArrayList<Key>(); //tableName="Daily", keys=["VisioNerdy"], ranges=[1329071400000]
>     Map<String, KeysAndAttributes> requestItems = new HashMap<String, KeysAndAttributes>();
>     for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
>     {
>         String key = keys.get(i);
>         if(ranges == null)
>             fkeys.add(new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(key)));
>         else
>             fkeys.add(new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(key))
>                     .withRangeKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(ranges.get(i).toString())));
>     }
>     requestItems.put(tableName, new KeysAndAttributes().withKeys(fkeys));
>     BatchGetItemRequest batchGetItemRequest = new BatchGetItemRequest().withRequestItems(requestItems);
>     BatchGetItemResult result = client.batchGetItem(batchGetItemRequest);
> ```

Any clues?

Comment: Could you please add your (eventually condensed) schema and the code fragment executing your query to ease analysis? Thanks!

Comment: Have edited the question to include them. Thanks!

Comment: You have "if(ranges == null)" but if a Table has a range key, a value is required; you can't omit it.

Comment: @AdamVandenberg This is a generic code that works for all Tables without or with range key. In this case, if(ranges == null) will not be executed, since "Daily" is executed with "ranges=[1329071400000]".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined the range attribute of your [Hash and Range Type Primary Key](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelPrimaryKey) as type *Number*, yet prepare its attribute value via `withS()` as type *String* for your request:

```
fkeys.add(new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(key))
        .withRangeKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(ranges.get(i).toString())));
```

Changing [withS(*String s*)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html#withS%28java.lang.String%29) to [withN(*String s*)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html#withN%28java.lang.String%29) should remedy your problem accordingly (confusingly both methods require a parameter of type *String*):

```
fkeys.add(new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(key))
        .withRangeKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withN(ranges.get(i).toString())));
```

Admittedly, the implicit weak typing of the [DynamoDB data types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelDataTypes) submission based on *String* parameters only doesn't exactly ease developing ;)

Comment: @Mani: Glad I could help - could you please upvote and especially accept the answer, if it solved your problem? This is desired here, both to get your issue out of sight and make room for open problems of others, as well as ensuring users stay motivated to help each other ;) See the FAQ [What is reputation?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) for details - thanks!