# Amazon DynamoDB getting items as a string

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am encountering difficulty in retrieving data from my table. I am using Amazon Dynamo DB and I have successfully populated my table. When I scan the table or use getItem, the returning information is of type AttributeValue. I have looked through the documentation and I can't find how you should process an AttributeValue to get it to become an int or string. The example code of scan from the Amazon Website has the information returned in a Dictionary object, but it is a dictionary with strings mapped to Attribute Values. Do you know of anyway to query a Dynamo DB table and store the result in something where strings are mapped to string or strings are mapped to integers?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), objects of [Class AttributeValue](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html) can be of type *String, Number, StringSet, NumberSet* and the class features respective getters/setters accordingly, e.g.:

- [public String getN()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html#getN%28%29) - *Numbers are positive or negative exact-value decimals and integers. A number can have up to 38 digits precision and can be between 10^-128 to 10^+126.*
- [public String getS()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html#getS%28%29) - *Strings are Unicode with UTF-8 binary encoding. The maximum size is limited by the size of the primary key (1024 bytes as a range part of a key or 2048 bytes as a single part hash key) or the item size (64k).*

Please note that the return value of `getN()` is still a string and must be converted by your Java string to number conversion method of choice accordingly. This implicit weak typing of the [DynamoDB data types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelDataTypes) retrieval/submission based on String parameters only is a bit unfortunate and doesn't exactly ease developing, see e.g. my answer to [Error in batchGetItem API in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276139/45773) for such an issue.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me that thinks the typing system (or lack thereof) is crazy.